# Rule of thumb for joining sentences

Tags: relative-clauses, run-on-sentences

I have two sentences:

> 1. data suffers from some artefacts.
> 2. this step is needed to reduce effect due to artefacts.

I'm struggling to choose the proper clause. In this case, would *from which* be suitable or not?

> this step is needed to reduce effect due to artefacts *from which* the
>   data suffers.

What is the rule of thumb for selecting a proper clause?

Comment: As trite as it may seem, choose one that is as simple and  straightforward as possible and says what you mean.   *This step reduces the effects of the data artifacts.*  OR *This step reduces the data artifact effects*

Comment: I would prefer "This step is needed to reduce effects due to artifacts the data suffers from." You can also say "due to the artifacts from which the data suffers", but this is awkward, IMO.

Comment: What Jim said. Writing shorter, but easier to understand sentences is always preferable to writing longer, but more difficult to understand ones.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* clean up the original sentence with "for which" in the question to make it perfectly grammatical, but I think I'd recommend the sentence below for clarity. Jim and David's suggestions are also possible.

> This step is needed to reduce the effect of the artifacts the data suffers from.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the simpler it is, the better.

To answer your question, your guess is correct, but awkward. The less correct, more natural way would be "which the data suffers from."

You can also take out "which" and simplify further, as per MonkeyPushButton's example.